# Meteor insert statement not inserting fields from client template

Tags: meteor, insert

I am writing a simple HTML form in which I am trying to insert values through a list and text fields. However, when I use the StudentMaster.insert statement, the statement does not populate any field of any document in any of the collection. It simply creates an object with an id field.

Here is my Code-

```
if(Meteor.isClient){
Template.nameT.events ({
"mousedown #save" : function(event){
 event.preventDefault();

StudentMaster.insert({admtype:$('#admtype').value});
StudentMaster.insert({enrollno:$('#enrollno').value});
StudentMaster.insert({thisyradm:$('#thisyradm').value});
},
"click #update" : function(event){
event.preventDefault();
rs = StudentMaster.find();
StudentMaster.insert({'admtype':$('#admtype').toString});
StudentMaster.insert({'enrollno':$('#enrollno').toString});
StudentMaster.insert({'thisyradm':$('#thisyradm').toString});
}
})
}
```

Here is the HTML -

```
<template name="nameT">
<select id = "admtype">
<option>New</option>
<option>Old</option>
</select>   <input type="text" placeholder = "Enroll No." id = "enrollno">
<input type="text" placeholder = "This Year Adm" id = "thisyradm"><br>
</template>

<head>
<title>School Project</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Welcome to School Project!</h1>
{{> nameT}}
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

your insertion process is wrong.your code basically inserts 3 `rows` in the database. suppose you have 3 values need to insert into the Database. the following snippet will hint you how do it assuming the attributes are `admtype` ,`enrollno` and `thisyradm`

```
StudentMaster.insert({
admtype:$('#admtype').value,
enrollno:$('#enrollno').value,
thisyradm:$('#thisyradm').value
});
```

And yes `insertion` returns an object id which is the `_id` value stored in the database.

Comment: This approach still does not solve the problem. It is inserting empty fields only.

Comment: everybody has been using this same approach. there's a chance that nothing is inserted into the db if you try to insert from client side and does not set permission. but in no way empty field will be inserted.

Comment: I just tried using collection.allow method to solve the problem but now it is throwing an "insert failed:internal server error" in the console window.

Comment: seems like you're in the right direction. it's failing because you're trying to insert from client side code and your `collection.allow` has some restrictions. return `true` in the allow. data will be inserted.

Comment: Just did that. Still no luck inserting fields in the collection.

Comment: there must be something wrong going on. you can ping me at `faysal@yahoo.com`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that insertion from client is allowed in `Collection.allow()` rules of `Student` collection as Meteor Docs says [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/allow),

If you want `admtype` ,`enrollno` and `thisyradm` as properties/columns of a single row/document then you have to change the insertion code as below

```
StudentMaster.insert({
admtype:$('#admtype').value,
enrollno:$('#enrollno').value,
thisyradm:$('#thisyradm').value
});
```

Other-wise it will create 3 different rows.

For updating a row, I will suggest using the `_id` of the row as selector for [Collection.update](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/update). Which is the return value of `Student.insert()` function.

Here also you have to ensure the `Student.allow()` rules allow update from client. I won't recommend updating collection from client. It is better to use server-side `Meteor.method` with `_id` and `update_data` as params for updating collection.